# How to push logs to splunk from log4net in .net core 6

Tags: log4net, splunk, asp.net-core-6.0

We are migrating from .net framework to .net core framework for our api.

We are trying to use log4net framework for logging Info and Error and then pushing them all to splunk since it was used in the existing api on .net framework.

But here in .net core im not getting a proper way or documentation to use log4net for logging and pushing the data to splunk. I have tried searching a lot and still not able to complete the implementation.

Can anyone please help me in this regard.

Thank you.
Vishwa

I have added configs for log4net and a logger class with methods, which i can use to log the Info and Error like below

```
namespace ABC
{
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Reflection;
    using log4net;
 
    public static class Logger
    {
        private static readonly ILog Log =      log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);

        public static void Info(this string className, string message)
        {
            log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["ActivityId"] = Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId;
            log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["LogType"] = className;
            Log.Info(message);
        }

        public static void Error(this string className, string message)
        {
            log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["ActivityId"] = Trace.CorrelationManager.ActivityId;
            log4net.LogicalThreadContext.Properties["LogType"] = className;
            Log.Error(message);
        }
    }
}
```

Now im stuck with the part to push logs to splunk . Any help would be appreciated

Comment: what did you use before that worked?

Comment: i was using .net framework. Now that we are migrating to .net core , not sure of a method to work it out. Im using log4net rolling file appender and it creates a log file with logs on local. Need to send those logs to splunk